# Docker - Libreoffice pid not found

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, libreoffice

I'm new in Docker (Rocky Linux) and I need to use jodconverter in java process. So I updated my Dockerfile as follow :

```
#Installing LibreOffice
COPY backend/LibreOffice_6.3.5.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm /usr/local/LibreOffice_6.3.5.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm
RUN cd /usr/local/LibreOffice_6.3.5.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm/RPMS/
RUN yum -y install /usr/local/LibreOffice_6.3.5.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm/RPMS/*.rpm;
```

I find libreoffice6.3 in /opt folder inside container. However "Libreoffice -version" doesn't work :

```
bash: Libreoffice: command not found
```

When the java process is executed i get the following error: **ServiceManager' started but its pid could not be found** :

```
OfficeProcessManager          : Submitting task 'Start' and waiting...
2023-08-03 13:51:37.133  INFO 1 --- [ProcessThread-0] 
org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcess    : Starting process with acceptString 
'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager' and 
profileDir '/usr/local/tomcat/temp/.jodconverter_socket_host-127.0.0.1_port- 
2002_tcpNoDelay-1'
2023-08-03 13:51:37.148  INFO 1 --- [ProcessThread-0] 
org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcess    : Started process; pid = -2
2023-08-03 13:51:37.149 ERROR 1 --- [TaskScheduler16] 
c.m.service.TransformationService     : ERROR convertToDocx: 
org.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: A process with acceptString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager' started but its pid could not be found
    at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcess.start(OfficeProcess.java:354)
    at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager.doStartProcessAndConnect(OfficeProcessManager.java:100)
    at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager.access$100(OfficeProcessManager.java:40)
    at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager$4.call(OfficeProcessManager.java:260)
    at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager$4.call(OfficeProcessManager.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

2023-08-03 13:51:37.150  INFO 1 --- [TaskScheduler16] 
 o.j.office.AbstractOfficeManagerPool     : Stopping the office manager pool...
2023-08-03 13:51:37.152  INFO 1 --- [TaskScheduler16] o.j.office.OfficeProcessManager          
: Submitting task 'Stop' and waiting...
2023-08-03 13:51:37.159  INFO 1 --- [ProcessThread-0] 
org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcess    : Trying to forcibly terminate process: 
'host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'; pid: -2
2023-08-03 13:51:37.166  INFO 1 --- [ProcessThread-0] o.j.office.OfficeProcessManager          
: process forcibly terminated with code 127
2023-08-03 13:51:37.166  INFO 1 --- [ProcessThread-0] o.j.office.OfficeProcessManager          
: process exited with code 127
2023-08-03 13:51:37.174  INFO 1 --- [TaskScheduler16] o.j.office.AbstractOfficeManagerPool     : Office manager stopped
```

This is my java code :

```
libreOfficeHome = libreoff.getValue();
        
        File initialFile = new File(workPath + "/" + fileName);
        LocalOfficeManager localOfficeManager = LocalOfficeManager.builder()
                .install()
                .officeHome(libreOfficeHome) //your path to openoffice
                .build();

        try {
            localOfficeManager.start();
            final DocumentFormat format = DocumentFormat.builder()
                    .from(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.DOCX)
                    .build();

            LocalConverter
                  .make()
                  .convert(new FileInputStream(initialFile))
                  .as(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.getFormatByMediaType("application/msword"))
                  .to(new File(targetFile))
                  .as(format)
                  .execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("ERROR convertToDocx: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            return null;
        } finally {
            OfficeUtils.stopQuietly(localOfficeManager);
        }
```

Same error with libreoffice 7.5

Comment: The command would be `libreoffice` (not `Libreoffice`), no?

Comment: exact but same result : [root@56eda4acbd64 tomcat]# libreoffice
bash: libreoffice: command not found
[root@56eda4acbd64 tomcat]# libreoffice -version
bash: libreoffice: command not found
[root@56eda4acbd64 tomcat]# libreoffice --version
bash: libreoffice: command not found

Comment: Did you check that the `PATH` environment variable contains the path to the executable, or that links to the executable from a know path exist? @DaveNewton The actual name of the executable is "soffice".

Comment: @thebusybee Either should work for normal installs :shrug:

Comment: @thebusybee : Path container is PATH=/usr/local/tomcat/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin. But soffice is in /opt/libreoffice6.3/program

Comment: @thebusybee : i add /opt/libreoffice6.3 in path variable (PATH=/usr/local/tomcat/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/libreoffice6.3/) but nothing changes

Comment: What happens if you execute " /opt/libreoffice6.3/program/soffice"?

Comment: Commonly there are soft links (for example in "/usr/bin") that point to the actual executable. Did you check that, as I suggested?

Comment: @thebusybee "Failed to open display - /opt/libreoffice6.3/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libcairo.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: @thebusybee about links : inside container i find only /opt/libreoffice6.3 that contains program folder that contains soffice and all the other .so file

Comment: The links would be in some of the other directories listed in `PATH`, as I wrote for example in "/usr/bin", not in "/opt/libreoffice6.3". -- Well, since I don't have the environment to reproduce, I cannot help further. It might be an incomplete installation, who knows? Hopefully some others can jump in. Good luck!